# ¿Como mostar campo de otra tabla por medio de llave foránea en laravel?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Buenas Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto para ir practicando laravel.

En mi proyecto los **usuarios** pueden hacer **recargas** por lo cual yo en una vita quiero mostrar el nombre del usuario con toda la información de la recarga , pero no he podido mostrar el nombre.

lo que quiero es mostrar el nombre del usuario el cual esta en otra tabla;

**tabla usuarios**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre', 30);
        $table->string('apellidos', 60);
        $table->string('sexo' , 15);
        $table->integer('edad');
        $table->string('correo' , 50)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**tabla recargas**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recargas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('usuario_id')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('cantidad_recarga' , 8,2);
        $table->dateTime('fecha_recarga');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios');
    });
}
```

**Modelo Usuario**

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['nombre' , 'apellidos' , 'edad' , 'sexo' , 'correo'];

   public function recargas()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recarga');
  }
}
```

**Modelo Recarga**

```
class Recarga extends Model
{
   public function usuario()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Usuario');
   }
}
```

**Controlador de Recargas**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Recarga;

class RecargaController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $recargas = Recarga::all();
    return view('recargas.index' , compact('recargas'));
}
```

**La vista donde quiero mostrar los datos**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('recargas.create') }}"> Nuevo recarga  </a>
<br>  
<br>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <th scope="col" >Id</th>
    <th scope="col" >Nombre</th>
    <th scope="col" >Cantida Recarga</th>
    <th scope="col" >Fecha Recarga</th>
    <th scope="col" >Acciones</th>

 </thead>
 <tbody>
    @foreach ($recargas as $recarga) 
       <tr>
         <th scope="row"> {{$recarga->id}} </th>
         <td>  {{-- Aqui quisiero mostrar el nombre --}} </td>
         <td> {{$recarga->cantidad_recarga}} </td>
         <td> {{$recarga->fecha_recarga}} </td>
         <td>             
            <form action="{{ route('recargas.destroy' , $recarga->id) }}" method="POST">
                  <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('recargas.edit', $recarga->id) }}">  Actualizar  </a>

                 {{csrf_field()}}
                 @method('DELETE')
                 <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
           </form>

        </td>
     </tr>
  @endforeach
```

**y por ultimo lo que me muestra el navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo en la otra respuesta que te muestran la ruta complicada usando joins, esto es totalmente **innecesario** cuando usas un framework como Laravel (o muchos otros) y tienes a Eloquent además.

Ya tienes las relaciones correctamente definidas entre tus modelos, lo que necesitas es replantear un poco la forma de abordar el problema, lo cual es muy sencillo y voy a retomar tus palabras:

> quiero mostrar el nombre del usuario con toda la información de la recarga

Teniendo en cuenta que es el usuario quien tiene muchas recargas, es el dueño de estas, por llamarlo así, y tú mismo le estás dando el orden (con tus palabras) en que debe hacerse la consulta.

Es mucho más fácil partir del usuario «dueño» de las recargas, que intentar partir de una recarga cualquiera y deducir si pertenece a nuestro usuario en cuestión o no.

En la vida real es más fácil preguntarle a alguien cuantas casas tiene, que ir preguntando de casa en casa a quien le pertenece esta.

Yendo a la práctica, cargas los datos de las recargas relacionadas con dicho usuario con Eager Loading, pero siempre partiendo del usuario:

```
public function index()
{
    $usuarios = User::with('recargas')->get();
    return view('recargas.index' , compact('usuarios'));
}
```

Y en la vista debes iterar primero a través de los usuarios y luego a través de cada recarga:

```
@foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)

  @foreach ($usuario->recargas as $recarga)
   <tr>
     <th scope="row"> {{$recarga->id}} </th>
     <td>  {{ $usuario->nombre }} </td>
     <td> {{$recarga->cantidad_recarga}} </td>
     <td> {{$recarga->fecha_recarga}} </td>
     <td>             
        <form action="{{ route('recargas.destroy' , $recarga->id) }}" method="POST">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('recargas.edit', $recarga->id) }}">  Actualizar  </a>

             {{csrf_field()}}
             @method('DELETE')
             <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
       </form>

      </td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya solucione el problema gracias a tu respuesta , pero si ahora quisiera ingresar un registro en la tabla **recargas** que debería de hacer

Comment: Eso es otro problema, fuera del alcance de esta pregunta. Revisa la documentación.

Comment: Disculpa me puedes decir en que sección porque no se en que parte buscarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas vincular ambos modelos, tienes varias opciones entre ellas:

- uso de los métodos `JOIN` para declarar tu consulta
- Eager loading

**MÉTODO JOIN**

Vamos con la primer opción, además de lo anterior identifico una relación de 1:M donde un usuario puede hacer muchas recargas, entonces tu consulta debería quedar así

```
$data = Usuario::join('recargas', 'users.id', 'recargas.usuario_id')
               ->select('usuarios.nombre', 'recargas.cantidad_recarga', 
                        'recargas.fecha_recargas')
               ->get();
```

De modo que en la vista ahora puedas recorrer lo que te llega de este modo

```
@foreach($data as $dato)
   {{ $dato->nombre }}
   {{ $dato->fecha_recarga }}
   {{ $dato->cantidad_recarga }}
@endforeach
```

Como puedes ver en el método `select()` indico cuales columnas quiero recuperar y las nombro para después recuperarlas en la vista

> El punto en como lo estabas haciendo, es que estaba mal, por que al
>   hacer `ModeloNombre::all();` solo te estas preocupando por recuperar
>   los datos de la tabla que esta asociada con ese modo, es decir cuando
>   pusiste `Recarga::all();` solo estas recuperando las columnas de la
>   tabla recargas pero no sus valores asociados con usuarios

**USO DE EAGER LOADING**

Viendo que tienes tus relaciones declaradas, puede ser del modo siguiente

```
$data = Usuario::with('recargas')->get();
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, en tu vista deberás recorrer los valores que te lleguen de este modo

```
@foreach($data as $d)
   {{ $d->nombre }}
   @foreach($d->recargas as $recarga)
      {{ $recarga->fecha_recarga }}
      {{ $recarga->cantidad_recarga }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> Cuando hago uso de `$d->recargas` estoy accediendo al nombre del
>   método que tu declaraste en el modelo Usuario llamado así `recargas`

De modo que obtendrás a cada usuario y todas sus recargas asociadas